How do i construct a polynomial
How do i construct a polynomial x1*x2*Ai(x1-x2)^n in python, n=6. I need it for approximation. Also I need to extract Ai. x1 and x2 are a set of experimental data.
I don't really know how to do it. I only know np.polyfit but it's not enough.

To construct the polynomial ₁ ⋅ ₂ ⋅ Ai ⋅ (₁ - ₂)^n  where n=6 and extract the value of Ai, you can use a custom Polynomial class in Python. Here's how you can do it:
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, *coeffs):
        if not coeffs:
            raise ValueError("Polynomial coefficients cannot be empty")
        self.coeffs = tuple(coeffs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Polynomial{self.coeffs}"

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Polynomial):
            raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Polynomial' and '{}'"
                            .format(type(other).__name__))
        return Polynomial(*(x + y for x, y in zip(self.coeffs, other.coeffs)))

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Polynomial):
            raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Polynomial' and '{}'"
                            .format(type(other).__name__))
        len_self = len(self.coeffs)
        len_other = len(other.coeffs)
        new_coeffs = [0.0] * (len_self + len_other - 1)
        for i in range(len_self):
            for j in range(len_other):
                new_coeffs[i + j] += self.coeffs[i] * other.coeffs[j]
        return Polynomial(*new_coeffs)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.coeffs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Polynomial):
            return False
        return self.coeffs == other.coeffs

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.coeffs[index]

    def degree(self):
        return len(self.coeffs) - 1

    def __str__(self):
        terms = [f"{c}x^{i}" if i > 1 else (f"{c}x" if i == 1 else str(c)) for i, c in enumerate(self.coeffs)]
        return " + ".join(terms[::-1])

def construct_polynomial(x2, A):
    coeffs = [0.0] * (len(A) + 1)
    for i, ai in enumerate(A):
        coeffs[i] = ai * (1 - 2 * x2) ** i
    return Polynomial(1 - x2) * Polynomial(x2) * Polynomial(*coeffs[::-1]), A


x2 = 0.5  # Example experimental data
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  # Example values for A0 to A6

polynomial, Ai_extracted = construct_polynomial(x2, A)

print("Constructed polynomial:", polynomial)
print("Extracted Ai values:", Ai_extracted)


Yes, but i need to get a set of Ai =( A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6)

function looks like this (1-x2)x2(A0 + A1(1-2x2)+ A2(1-2x2)*2 + A3(1-2x2)*3 + A4(1-2x2)*4 + A5(1-2x2)*5 + A6(1-2*x2)**6)

I've been working on it. Please let me know if you find any issues in the updated code.
